# Получить единственное значение для каждой переменной

Tags: sql, perl

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Ниже кусок кода, которым я хочу получить из таблицы значении одного столбца, в данном случае $PG1...$PG10 должны иметь значении 600...610 соответственно. 
Но при выводе на печать они дублируются по нескольку раз, то-есть выводится:

```
600
601
...
610
600
601
...
610
```

Как получить каждое значение только один раз и присвоить его переменной?

```
my $dbqueryPRODGRP = $db->prepare("select f1 from DPTDAT group by f1");
$dbqueryPRODGRP->execute();
my @rowPRODGRPs;
while (my ($rowPRODGRP)=$dbqueryPRODGRP->fetchrow_array()) {
  push @rowPRODGRPs, $rowPRODGRP;
  foreach $rowPRODGRP(@rowPRODGRPs)
  {
    my (
    $PG1,$PG2,$PG3,$PG4,$PG5,$PG6,$PG7,$PG8,$PG9,$PG10,)=@rowPRODGRPs;
 print $PG1."\n", $PG2."\n",$PG3."\n",$PG4."\n",$PG5."\n",$PG6."\n",$PG7."\n",$PG8."\n",$PG9."\n",$PG10."\n";
    }
}
```

Исправленная версия которая заработала.

```
my $dbqueryPRODGRP = $db->prepare("select f1 from DPTDAT group by f1 order by f1");
$dbqueryPRODGRP->execute();
my @rowPRODGRPs;#Задаем имя массиву
while (my ($rowPRODGRP)=$dbqueryPRODGRP->fetchrow_array()) {
  push @rowPRODGRPs, $rowPRODGRP;#Записываем каждый результат в лист массива
}
```

Comment: Вы в цикле берете первую строку, добавляете в массив. Тут же печатаете весь массив. После чего берете вторую строку, добавляете в массив (в массиве теперь 2 строки) и опять печатаете весь массив целиком. Если вам нужен массив, то сначала его весь заполняете, а после цикла чтения из базы (после `}` относящейся к `while`) печатаете. Или без всяких массивов печатаете строку как только получили ее из БД

Comment: Да вдобавок вы делаете foreach по массиву, т.е. перебираете его элементы и для каждого элемента получаете в переменные первые 10 элементов этого же массива и печатаете их все. Т.е. если в массиве 3 элемента foreach выполнится 3 раза и вы 3 раза распечатаете весь массив и того будет напечатано 9 значений

Comment: *"Исправленная версия"* -- то есть решили пойти сложным путём всесто простого?

Comment: SQL-запрос "select distinct f1 from DPTDAT order by f1" вернёт отсортированный список всех уникальных значений (без повторов), найденных в таблице. После получения списка его можно использовать "как есть", без дополнительных ухищрений в коде. Бонус - если записей в таблице много, то в текущем варианте вы их все сначала вычитываете из БД, все загружаете в память вашего ПО, а затем все, кроме десяти, просто отбрасываете. С использованием distinct во всех вышеописанных процессах участвует только 10 записей. Кстати, значений от 600 до 610 - 11 штук, а переменных у вас 10.

Answer (score 0):

Про ошибки в логике вам уже написали. Могу только заметить, что всё то же самое можно сделать намного проще:

```
use DDP;
my $rowPRODGRPs = $db->selectcol_arrayref( 'select f1 from DPTDAT group by f1' );
p $rowPRODGRPs;
```

Теперь в `$rowPRODGRPs` содержится ссылка на массив значений `f1`. При условии, что в таблице есть значения `1`, `2` и `3`, будет выведено (строкой `p $rowPRODGRPs;`):

```
\ [
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3
]
```

Присвоить значения элментов массива переменным:

```
my ( $PG1, $PG2, $PG3 ) = @{$rowPRODGRPs};
```

Но тут возникают два вопроса:

1. Зачем?
2. Что произойдёт, если будет прочитано больше значений, чем у вас написано переменных?

В любом случае сама по себе необходимость присвоения значений массива отдельным переменным вызывает как минимум вопросы. Фактически вы просто создаёте дубликаты уже и так имеющихся данных, и это мероприятие не кажется особо осмысленным.

Answer (score 0):

для получения уникальных значений используйте хеш.

```
for $value ( 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2 ) {
    $uniq{ $value }++;
}

print keys %$uniq; # 1 2 3
( $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4 ) =  keys %$uniq;

# Количество сколько раз встречалось значение
print values %$uniq; # 1 3 2
```